# How to mount a volume with ReadWriteOnce in init containers of different pods, running sequentially?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-volume

I tried the following:

1. Create persistent volume claim:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   metadata:
     name: test
   spec:
     accessModes:
     - ReadWriteOnce
     resources:
       requests:
         storage: 1Mi
   ```
2. Create pod 1 using that persistent volume claim, mounting it only in init container:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: test1
   spec:
     initContainers:
       - name: init
         image: opensuse/leap:15.5
         command: ['sleep', '1']
         volumeMounts:
         - name: volume
           mountPath: /mnt/volume
     containers:
       - name: main
         image: opensuse/leap:15.5
         command: ['sleep', '1073741824']
     volumes:
     - name: volume
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: test
   ```
3. Wait until init container completed.
4. Create pod 2 using that persistent volume claim, mounting it only in init container:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: test2
   spec:
     initContainers:
       - name: init
         image: opensuse/leap:15.5
         command: ['sleep', '1']
         volumeMounts:
         - name: volume
           mountPath: /mnt/volume
     containers:
       - name: main
         image: opensuse/leap:15.5
         command: ['sleep', '1073741824']
     volumes:
     - name: volume
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: test
   ```

I think that should work because the volume is mounted only in the init containers and these don’t run in parallel.

What happens instead is that the second pod fails to attach the volume because it’s still attached to the first pod.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age    From                     Message
  ----     ------              ----   ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  3m14s  attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-81c18505-3239-4636-8506-ec5cb73da837" Volume is already used by pod(s) test1
  Warning  FailedMount         71s    kubelet                  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[volume], unattached volumes=[volume], failed to process volumes=[]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Is there a way to make it work? I use the rook-ceph-block storage class.

The problem appeared in a larger context. The pods were created as part of Deployments. When upgrading the Deployment, the second pod was created while the first pod was still running because of using the RollingUpdate strategy. The problem can be worked around by using the Recreate strategy because that would delete the first pod before creating the second. However, that creates down time while the init container is running. In the real case, the init container prepares some data, caching data in the persistent volume, and passes it to the main container via an ephemeral volume. Only one such init container should run at the same time.